# Could not find class x referenced from method y on test project

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, tdd, robotium

I'm using robotium test framework on an app I am actually developing, I runned it at the very first stage of the project, and it was ok, but yesterday I implemented more tests and got very frustrated because it seems like the test project cant find any of my classes to test. It happened after I updated some stuff at the SDK manager, but I am not really sure if it has something to do with my problem. 
Anyway there is an example of the output at logcat:

> 05-06 16:30:27.541: E/dalvikvm(24080): Could not find class 'com.tuntzme.controller.activities.ActivityLogin', referenced from method com.tuntzme.test.activities.ActivityLoginTest.

there is one of my testcases:

```
public class ActivityCadastroTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityCadastro>{

private Solo solo;

public ActivityCadastroTest() {
    super(ActivityCadastro.class);
}

public void TesteCadastroCamposVazios() {
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("activity_errada", ActivityCadastro.class);
    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.menu_item_pronto_cadastro);
    solo.waitForText(MensagensException.CAMPO_EMAIL_VAZIO.toString());

    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_email_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.EMAIL_TESTE_SUCESSFULL.value());
    solo.waitForText(MensagensException.CAMPO_SENHA_VAZIO.toString());
}

public void TesteCadastroEmailInvalido() {
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("activity_errada", ActivityCadastro.class);
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_email_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.EMAIL_TESTE_WRONG_FORMAT.value());
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_senha_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.SENHA_TESTE.value());
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_confirmar_senha_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.SENHA_TESTE.value());
    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.menu_item_pronto_cadastro);
    solo.waitForText(MensagensException.EMAIL_INVALIDO.toString());
}

public void TesteCadastroSenhaDivergente() {
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("activity_errada", ActivityCadastro.class);
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_email_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.EMAIL_TESTE_SUCESSFULL.value());
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_senha_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.SENHA_TESTE.value());
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_confirmar_senha_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.SENHA_TESTE_DIVERGENTE.value());
    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.menu_item_pronto_cadastro);
    solo.waitForText(MensagensException.SENHAS_NAO_COINCIDEM.toString());
}

public void TesteCadastroSucesso() {
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("activity_errada", ActivityCadastro.class);
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_email_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.EMAIL_TESTE_SUCESSFULL.value());
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_senha_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.SENHA_TESTE.value());
    solo.enterText(com.tuntzme.R.id.edit_text_confirmar_senha_cadastro, SharedStuff.Strings.SENHA_TESTE.value());
    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.menu_item_pronto_cadastro);
    solo.waitForActivity(ActivityLogin.class);
}
```

}

my test project manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tuntzme.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.tuntzme" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
<instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.tuntzme" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
```

and finally there is my order and export stuff for the test project
[image]

Hope someone can help me, I would really appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

you can try using other methods of waitFor:

> solo.waitForText(); //if a certain text appears after the loading is done
>
> solo.waitForView(); //if a certain view is shown after the load screen is done.

or you can use

> solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected MyActivity", "MyActivity");

use some delays like

> Thread.sleep(1500);

or

> solo.sleep(1500);